# Choose a number from an array

Tags: c++, c, random

Is there any function or method to randomly choose a number (or 2 numbers or more) from an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Random Number from fix Set of numbers in iphone ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943666/generate-random-number-from-fix-set-of-numbers-in-iphone), [How to get 2 random (different) elements from a c++ vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288171/how-to-get-2-random-different-elements-from-a-c-vector), etc etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on how many numbers you need, the size of the array, and whether the array needs to retain its order, you could use `std::random_shuffle` to reorder the array and then just loop from 0..n-1 to get n random numbers. This works better when you want to get a lot of numbers relative to the length of the array.

If that doesn't seem appropriate, you can just use `srand()` and `rand() % n` as an index into the array to get a pretty good approximation of a random selection.

Answer (score 3):

For your array of size n, just generate a random number in the 0..n-1 range, then select the number indexed in the array.

Comment: Just be careful to make sure you're giving an equal probability to each element.  Something like floor(rand(0..1) * n) should do the trick.

Comment: only if you care about traceability or likewise, for quick purposes, old rand() is fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
int RandomElement(int *array, int size)
{
   return array[ rand() % size ];     
}
```

if you accept rand as a random number generator.

Answer (score 2):

```
randomElement = arr[rand() % ARRAY_SIZE];
```

This is the simplest approach.  You could use the `Boost.Random` library if you want to do something more complicated, like assign different probabilities to different elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

rand() % n is often pretty much non-random, at least with legacy (bad) random generators (there are plenty of them, beware).

Better is ((double)rand() / MAX_RAND) * n if you can afford the conversion. Or use a random generator whose lower bits are known to be random, and do rejection on the lower log n bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select two random numbers from the array, without reusing the same number the following would work

```
int array[SIZE];

i = rand() % SIZE;
rand1 = array[i];
j = 1 + rand() % (SIZE - 2);
rand2 = array[(i + j) % SIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<cstdlib>

  template<typename T,size_t n>
  T randElem(T (&a)[n])
  {

        return a[rand() % n];
  }


  int main()
  {
      int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};

      int n=randElem<int>(a);
      std::cout<<n;
  }
```